# Return multiple rows from database

Tags: c#, arrays, web-services

I am using the following method in a web service to return a single set of data -

```
int T = 0;
res.rows = new users[1];
        int cnt = 0;

        while (reader.Read())
        {

            if (T == 0)
            {

                res.rows[T] = new users();

                res.rows[T].age = (String)reader["age"];
                res.rows[T].height = (String)reader["height"];

                T = T + 1;

            }
            cnt = cnt + 1;               
        }

        return res;
```

I have currently designed this to return one row of data, set here `res.rows = new users[1];` then `j==0` then brings back the first row of data.

My question being is how could I modify this to bring back multiple/all rows of data?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of objects are res and users?

Comment: Why don't you create a User class and set Age and Height properties and then populate them via your reader and return a List of User from your method??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to keep minimum changes in your code it would look like this,

```
int T = 0;
res.rows = new List<User>();
    int cnt = 0;

    while (reader.Read())
    {

        //if (T == 0)
        {
            User u =new users();
            res.rows.Add(u);

            res.rows[T].age = (String)reader["age"];
            res.rows[T].height = (String)reader["height"];

            T = T + 1;

        }
        cnt = cnt + 1;               
    }

    return res;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class User
{
    private string m_Age;
    private string m_Height;

    public User() { }

    public string Age
    {
        get { return m_Age; }
        set { m_Age = value; }
    }

    public string Height
    {
        get { return m_Height; }
        set { m_Height = value; }
    }

}
```

---

```
var rows = new List<User>();
while (reader.Read())
{

     var row = new User();
     row.Age = reader["age"];
     row.Height = reader["height"];
     rows.Add(row);
}

res.rows = rows; //if the res.rows property is an array then you can change this line to res.rows = rows.ToArray();

return res;
```